# Building XCode From Command Line Issues (Updating Entitlements file location)

Tags: iphone, xcode, terminal, entitlements

The first error is a warning for complier 'com.apple.compilers.gcc.4_0' I don't know if this is okay and I can just not worry about it.
The second tells me that my entitlements file is no longer at that location.  I know this and I thought I had correctly updated it in Xcode's info window.  This project builds fine in Xcode.

```
Michael-Lindahls-Mac:~ michaellindahl$ xcodebuild -project /Users/michaellindahl/Dropbox/Xcode/App/app.xcodeproj -alltargets
2011-01-03 11:41:51.591 xcodebuild[15162:60f] warning: compiler 'com.apple.compilers.gcc.4_0' is based on missing compiler 'com.apple.compilers.gcc.4_0'
=== BUILD NATIVE TARGET app OF PROJECT app WITH THE DEFAULT CONFIGURATION (Release) ===
Check dependencies
[BEROR]CodeSign error: The entitlements file '/Users/michaellindahl/Dropbox/Xcode/deletedAppFile/Entitlements.plist' is missing



** BUILD FAILED **
```

Comment: Please don't alter the question, because the answers won't make sense then. Just post another question for a different issue.

Comment: Alright, I just didn't want to ask millions of question, so I thought modifying it was the way to go, thanks for informing me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entitlements.plist is used for ad-hoc distributions.  You're building all targets - does this build work when you do only debug?  I reckon it would.

Also - does the file actually exist in the location suggested?

If you don't need the Entitlements.plist functionality, open up your project, go to Build settings, search for it, and remove the key to it - that will also get rid of the error.

Comment: I ran it again, this time letting it sit, before I think I clicked the return key when it stopped going thinking I had to, I think that was a mistake, however since it still worked after doing so I thought thats what I was supposed to do, anyways, I now I have a new error... edited question